# Where is groovy.swing.factory.BindProxyFactory?

Tags: java, swing, groovy, java-2d

When trying to use GraphicsBuilder, I get a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` for `groovy.swing.factory.BindProxyFactory`.

This is my environment:

```
% java -version
java version "1.6.0_10"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_10-b33)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 11.0-b15, mixed mode)
% groovy --version
Groovy Version: 1.5.7 JVM: 1.6.0_10
% ls ~/.groovy/lib/graphicsbuilder*
graphicsbuilder-0.6.1.jar
...
```

And this is what I try to do:

```
 % groovysh
Groovy Shell (1.5.7, JVM: 1.6.0_10)
Type 'help' or '\h' for help.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
groovy:000> import groovy.swing.SwingBuilder
groovy:000> import groovy.swing.j2d.GraphicsBuilder  
groovy:000> import groovy.swing.j2d.GraphicsPanel
groovy:000> def gb = new GraphicsBuilder()  
ERROR java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: groovy.swing.factory.BindProxyFactory
        at groovysh_evaluate.run (groovysh_evaluate:5)
        ...
```

Where is BindProxyFactoryBean?

Answer (score 1):

It's in the Groovy 1.6 builds, not the 1.5.7 builds.  Apparently GfxBuilder 6.1 was built against the Groovy 1.6 codebase.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is correct. Groovy 1.6.x is required for GfxBuilder 6.1 and onwards.